# Getting empty list when using glob.glob in python to return paths from pc

Tags: python, path, glob

I use jupyter notebook anaconda, I need to read  paths of specific files from folder

```
paths = glob.glob('E:\master\neural network\mit-bih-arrhythmia-database-1.0.0/*.atr', recursive=True)
```

```
paths = glob.glob('E:\master\neural network\mit-bih-arrhythmia-database-1.0.0/*.atr')
```

```
**paths = glob.glob('E:\master\neural network\mit-bih-arrhythmia-database-1.0.0\*.atr')**
```

I try these lines but paths returns empty

Comment: see your path `E:\master\neural network\mit-bih-arrhythmia-database-1.0.0/*.atr` it should be `E:\master\neural network\mit-bih-arrhythmia-database-1.0.0\*.atr`

Comment: @komatiraju032 That's still wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need double backslashes because they're special characters:

```
paths = glob.glob('E:\\master\\neural network\\mit-bih-arrhythmia-database-1.0.0\\*.atr', recursive=True)
```

You can also use an `r` string instead, so that all the characters will be interpreted as normal:

```
paths = glob.glob(r'E:\master\neural network\mit-bih-arrhythmia-database-1.0.0\*.atr', recursive=True)
```